# CPanel: How to use two different domains in one hosting account, keeping url?

Tags: apache, hosting, dns, cpanel

Right now there's two different accounts, with both domains having each their own hosting account,
for similar website (let's say domain.fr and domain.co.uk)!
I've merged the two websites into one (currently hosted as 0.0.0.0/site/language ),
making it multilanguage! The script just need a prefix on root,
such as like www.domain.com/english/ or www.domain.com/french.

This works as expected, if only a domain is used, but I would like to use two different domains `(domain.fr / domain.co.uk)`.

So, I want to catch the current request URL, to know what language to display. What's important is that, the request urls keep persistent.

For example,

```
http://domain.co.uk/language_english
http://domain.co.uk/language_english/somepage.php
http://domain.co.uk/language_english/somedirectory/someotherpage.php
```

While,

```
http://domain.fr/language_french
http://domain.fr/language_french/somepage.php
http://domain.fr/language_french/somedirectory/someotherpage.php
```

This two domains are actuall hosted in same hosting account, let's said

```
127.0.0.1/language_variable/somepage.php
```

Any suggestions or good practices?

Comment: you're not 100% clear. please simplify and give better examples.

Comment: Hi, I dont know how to explain this better. My website checks what's the domain name and I change the texts variables to show the right language. I could do this trough url: www.mydomain.com/language/home.php. For example, mydomain.com/english/home.php would show a homepage in english, where mydomain.com/french/home.php in french. This works fine with a single domain, byt I want to use two diferent domain names, pointing to the same site. let's say mydomain.co.uk/english/home.php shows the homepage in english (and as you see, the domain is not .com), also, mydomain.fr/french/home.php in french

Comment: The thing is that, I want to mask www.mydomain.com, with .co.uk or .fr (they are both, masking the .com ). The website is just one! I dont know how to explain this better

Comment: Having a multilanguage website, let's say, http://domain.com/language/home.php (where language is a variable, that can be, english, french, etc). How can I have multiple domain names, that point to the original domain.com and mask it ? For example, http://domain.co.uk/english/home.php or http://domain.fr/french/home.php, being truth that http://domain.co.uk/french/home.php would give a french site, because .co.uk or .fr are actual masks. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score -1):

If I got your question , It's a feature in Web Hosting's solution which is called Addon Domains and depend on hosting company that how many Addon Domain they let you to put into one account !